# How can I put an initial value on my TextFormField with a Controller?

Tags: flutter, forms, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-textformfield

How can I display my "teamName" value in the AlertDialog form while keeping the controller and not use "InitialValue" from my TextFormField? This is when I update the team name, I want the form to show it's name when the AlertDialog shows up. I am new to flutter, if you need anything else from my code just tell me.

```
AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
                                      title: const Text(
                                          "Modifier le nom de votre équipe"),
                                      content: Form(
                                        key: _thekey,
                                        child: TextFormField(
                                          controller: textController,
                                          validator: (val) => val?.length == 0
                                              ? "Indiquez un nom d'équipe s'il vous plait"
                                              : null,
                                          onSaved: (val) =>
                                          textController.text = val!,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      actions: [
                                        ElevatedButton(
                                            onPressed: (() {
                                              teamName = textController.text;
                                              print("le nom de la teamsss est : $teamName");
                                              setState(() {
                                                print(
                                                    "le nom de l'équipe est: $teamName");
                                                updateTeam(
                                                    team.idTeam,
                                                    textController,
                                                    idCoach,
                                                    context);

                                              });
                                            }),
                                            child: const Text("Modifier"))
                                      ],
                                    );
                                    showDialog(
                                        barrierDismissible: true,
                                        context: context,
                                        builder: (BuildContext ctx) {
                                          return alert;
                                        });
```

The alertDialog is supposed to get the teamName from a ListView. The prints with "$teamName" shows the right name, the update method works but I just want the field to have the initial name on it.

This is the update method if you need it as well

```
updateTeam(idTeam, textController, idCoach, context) async {
  final statAccess = DatabaseModel();
  SharedPreferences sp = await _pref;
  idCoach = sp.getInt("id");
  String nameControl = textController.text;
  print("le nameControl est: $nameControl");
  if (nameControl.isEmpty) {
    alertDialog("le nom est vide", false);
  } else {
    Teams team =
        Teams(idTeam: idTeam, nameTeam: nameControl, xidCoach: idCoach);
    await statAccess.updateTeam(team).then((value) {
      print(value);
      if (value == 1) {
        alertDialog("Mise à jour réussie", true);
        Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
      } else {
        alertDialog("la mise à jour à foiré", false);
      }
    }).catchError((error) {
      print(error);
      alertDialog("CA A VRAIMENT FOIRER", false);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TextEditingController.fromValue(` to set initial value

```dart
TextEditingController.fromValue(
      TextEditingValue(text: "MYInitial Value"));
```

If you like show hint use `hintText`

```dart
 TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "myHint text"
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. However, can you tell me where to put this? I've just tried to paste this after "controller:". It shows "My initial Value" but then when I press the button my print shows that the form is send empty.

Comment: Can you try changing `AlertDialog alert(context) => AlertDialog(`  and use `return alert(context);`

Comment: So you want me to change "AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(....) by return alert(context)? Because then when do I set the "alert" variable that is returned by the "showDialog"?

Comment: yes, You like to pass a string as initial value and then fetch update data from it ?

Comment: So when I click on an Icon that's in a ListTile, I want an AlertDialog to show up with a textFormField witch is set with the name that was in the ListTile. That AlertDialog has a single button "update" that is supposed to send the TextFormField value to the "updateTeam" method. Right now, everything works exept I can't show the initial name on the field.

Comment: Not sure why using `controller TextEditingController.fromValue(` is not working. let me share a complete snippet

Comment: Okayyy I solved my problem! First of all I used your "TextEditingController.fromValue(..." but THEN I used "onChanged" to put the new string on a variable. I send this variable to the update method afterwards. Thx for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the suggestions provided by yeasin sheikh also please add a stateful builder in the alert dialog for the state to be set like

```dart
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, setState) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Title of Dialog"),
          content: Text("some content"),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                });
              },
              child: Text("setstateexample"),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: I have changed my code, using the return AlertDialog just like you two have advised me. In the "content", I have just like my original code the Form and the TextFormField. I have put the "TextEditingController.FromValue" in the "controller:"  widget. When I then edit the text and send it, it appears that it send a "null" value.

Comment: Try adding a static value first just to see if it works as expected

Comment: it does work when I put a simple String the parameter of the update method. It looks like the validator or onSaved is not changing the value of textcontroller.text.